# WPF - Container recycling for Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, containers, recycle

I have an itemscontrol whose itemspanel is set to use a canvas. The itemtemplate Im using happens to be quite expensive to create, and the itemssource collection bound changes frequently, and so I'd like to use some kind of container recycling.

How would I go about this?